# How to access ModelState errors in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, telerik, modelstate

I'm currently working on an ASP.Net Core project that is using Telerik tools for the UI. I'm trying to use their notification widget to display errors/success messages. I was thinking I could do this by grabbing the info in the ModelState and putting those messages into the notification. My only issue is I can't find how to access the ModelState errors from javascript.

This is what I was trying and ideally I would like something like this:

```
$(function () {
    var notificationWidget = $("#notification").data("kendoNotification");

    var modelStates = ViewData.ModelState.Values;
    for (var modelState in modelStates) {
        for (var message in modelState.Errors) {
            notificationWidget.show(message);
        }
    }
});
```

I just want to be able to loop through the ModelState errors and use the messages as I need.

If this way is not possible I'm thinking I may have to do an ajax call or something back to my controller and have a function there that spits out the ModelState errors.

Any help is greatly appreciated!